# Safe GPU temperatures

Tags: temperature, gpu

What temperatures are safe for a GPU?

Comment: Celsius or Fahrenheit? ;-)

Comment: Andreas being in Sweden, I guess it's Celsius! ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GPUs can handle a larger heat level than CPUs. At idle they are often in the range of 50-70 °C.

> Max is more like 100 - 110 °C.

For example; checkout the specifications for the [NVidia GTX 275](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gtx_275_us.html) max (recommended) operating temperature is 105 °C.